# Scraping multiple webpages using getURIAsynchronous()

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am a novice in R. I am trying to scrape multiple https web pages using the `getURIAsynchronous()` function from the `RCurl` package. However, for each and every url, the function was returning "" as the result.

I tried using the `url.exists()` function from the same package to see if it returns TRUE or FALSE. To my surprise, it returned the value as FALSE. But the url exists.

Since these https urls I am using are my company specific urls, I am not in a position to provide examples here due to confidentiality reasons. However, using `readLines()` successfully extracts all html content from the website. But this is slow and time-consuming for thousands of urls. Any idea why `getURIAsynchronous()` is returning "" instead of scraping the html content? My focus here is to only scrape the entire html content and I can parse the data myself.

Is there any other package out there than can help me scrape multiple https websites faster instead of doing one page at a time?

UPDATE: Below is a small example similar to what I have been trying to do. In this case, its just a few urls to scrape but in my project, I have few thousand of them. When I try to extract text using a similar code below, I get "" for all urls.

```
library(RCurl)

source_url <- c("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html", "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html")

multi_urls <- getURIAsynchronous(source_url)
multi_urls <- as.list(multi_urls)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which specific URL you are trying to scrape from, but the code below will demonstrate how to loop through several URLs, and scrape data from each.  Maybe you can leverage this code to achieve your specific goal(s).

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#create a master dataframe to store all of the results
complete <- data.frame()

yearsVector <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
#position is not needed since all of the info is stored on the page
#positionVector <- c("qb", "rb", "wr", "te", "ol", "dl", "lb", "cb", "s")
positionVector <- c("qb")
for (i in 1:length(yearsVector)) {
    for (j in 1:length(positionVector)) {
        # create a url template 
        URL.base <- "http://www.nfl.com/draft/"
        URL.intermediate <- "/tracker?icampaign=draft-sub_nav_bar-drafteventpage-tracker#dt-tabs:dt-by-position/dt-by-position-input:"
        #create the dataframe with the dynamic values
        URL <- paste0(URL.base, yearsVector[i], URL.intermediate, positionVector[j])
        #print(URL)

        #read the page - store the page to make debugging easier
        page <- read_html(URL)

        #find records for each player
        playersloc <- str_locate_all(page, "\\{\"personId.*?\\}")[[1]]
        # Select the first column [, 1] and select the second column [, 2]
        players <- str_sub(page, playersloc[, 1] + 1, playersloc[, 2] - 1)
        #fix the cases where the players are named Jr.
        players <- gsub(", ", "_", players)

        #split and reshape the data in a data frame
        play2 <- strsplit(gsub("\"", "", players), ',')
        data <- sapply(strsplit(unlist(play2), ":"), FUN = function(x) { x[2] })
        df <- data.frame(matrix(data, ncol = 16, byrow = TRUE))
        #name the column names
        names(df) <- sapply(strsplit(unlist(play2[1]), ":"), FUN = function(x) { x[1] })


        #store the temp values into the master dataframe
        complete <- rbind(complete, df)
    }
}
```

Also . . .

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

site <- 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id&order_by_asc=&offset=0' 

webpage <- read_html(site)
draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
draft <- html_table(draft_table)[[1]]


jump <- seq(0, 800, by = 100)
site <- paste('http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?',
              'request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=',
              '&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0',
              '&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y',
              '&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=',
              '&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id',
              '&order_by_asc=&offset=', jump, sep="")

dfList <- lapply(site, function(i) {
    webpage <- read_html(i)
    draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
    draft <- html_table(draft_table)[[1]]
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ryguy72! I am actually trying to use RCurl package to do parallel web scraping in R. I am able to do it using readLines() function and it works flawlessly. But it is slow and takes time since it only scrapes one url at a time. I am trying to use RCurl's getURIAsynchronous() function for parallel web scraping. I tried it on some websites like IMDB outside my organization and it does the job better. But I am not able to scrape any https page specific to my organization for some reason. If I was able to do it, It would cut down my processing time by half.